# How to make sure VSCode disables spacing for * , % , and /

Tags: c++, coding-style, visual-studio-code

I'm coding in C++ and I'm trying to follow the coding conventions that are listed in here https://www.docs.uwarg.com/computer-vision/coding-conventions/. One of the coding conventions is this `No spaces around *, /, % and operators with higher precedence than them (e.g. ++, --, ::, !) with the exceptions of c-style casts and the sizeof operator, which should only have a space preceding them.` . I don't know how to configure this and I'm following Google's C++ style guide.

Comment: Type it the way it tells you. If you're asking about enforcement, use a tool like clang-format. VSCode doesn't do much of anything with regards to style.

Comment: so how would i do it with clang format?

Comment: You're either following Google's style guide or the one you linked. They are very different from each other. Google's style is a preset in clang-format. This other style may not be possible with their weird rules about operator spacing. If you want help with clang-format, you'll need to try to help yourself first, I would be happy to help with any issues you run into on the way.